# How do I use PayPal Access Token in Android SDK?

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm integrating PayPal in my Android app. I have successfully done the part where we can redirect to Paypal Activity by setting price, currency, and PayPalPaymentIntent. What I'm looking for is not available anywhere. I want to make Paypal transaction by using the access token. I'm getting token from the server-side. My client do not want to set the price from app side so that's why he's sending me the token.

My question is how do I set the token in PayPalPayment instead of price and currency? Below is my existing code.

```
private fun processPaypalPayment() {
    val paypalPayment =
        PayPalPayment(BigDecimal("1"), "USD", "Test", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE)
    val intent = Intent(this@PackagesActivity, PaymentActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config)
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, paypalPayment)
    startActivityForResult(intent, PAYPAL_REQ_CODE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access token is the wrong term. What you need from the server is for it to create a PayPal order ID (via the v2/checkout/orders API) and send this id to your app, for the approval flow. After approval you communicate the id back the server so it can capture it, store any resulting successful capture in its database, and immediately return the result of the capture (success or particular error) to the calling app.

Documentation for such a server-side integration with Native Checkout for Android [can be found here](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/in-app/android/server-side/), basically you need to use the actions `.set()` with the created id as a parameter

```
  payPalButton.setup(
      createOrder = CreateOrder { createOrderActions ->
          val orderId: String // Retrieve your order ID from your server-side integration
          createOrderActions.set(orderId)
      }
  )
```

---

If this code doesn't look familiar you are probably attempting to use a deprecated android SDK rather than the current Native Checkout one. Don't do that, it's very old and won't be accepted by the app store.

Comment: Thank you. I do realize now that I'm using the old SDK. But I'm receiving this response from Paypal server: 

'TOKEN' => 'EC-7W874567W83167306',
'TIMESTAMP' => '2022-01-17T06:01:36Z',
'CORRELATIONID' => 'ebab50506d71f',
'ACK' => 'Success',
'VERSION' => '123',
'BUILD' => '56144363',
'paypal_link' => 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-7W874567W83167306',

I do not have Order ID.

Comment: That's from the old NVP API, not the current REST v2/checkout/orders . You can use the EC token but you should change it to a current integration

Comment: How can I use the token? If I can use them somehow, it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: See the above answer

Comment: Can I replace orderID with token?